# Moving WordPress from Linux to Windows Server 2012 - database issue

Tags: mysql, linux, database, windows, wordpress

I have been tasked with transferring a WordPress website from a test server (Linux server) to the client's own server (Windows 2012 server).

So far so good as I have transferred the files and created the new database to go with it. Also updated the wp-config.php file to include the new database info.

As per documentation I have read elsewhere, I changed the DB_HOST in the config file from 'localhost' to the IP address of the new server.

When I try to load the website I get the following error:

**Notice: Use of undefined constant DB_HOST - assumed 'DB_HOST' in D:\inetpub\wwwroot\website\wp-includes\load.php on line 350
Warning: mysql_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in D:\inetpub\wwwroot\website\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1482
Warning: mysql_connect(): [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. (trying to connect via tcp://DB_HOST:3306) in D:\inetpub\wwwroot\website\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1482
Warning: mysql_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in D:\inetpub\wwwroot\website\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1482**

I can't make sense of it! Can anyone help?

I should mention that phpmyAdmin and mySQL are installed and apparently correctly set up on the Windows Server.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post the exact line where you assign DB_HOST? Also, what version of WordPress, MySQL, etc.

Comment: Hi Joel C, the exact line is '/** define('DB_HOST', '78.137.113.80'); */' Wordpress version is 4.3.1

Comment: From your paste, it looks like the whole line is commented out with the /* and */ on either end. Can you try removing those marts at each end and see if it works?

Comment: phpmyAdmin Version: 4.0.10.7

Comment: @JoelC yes! But now I'm getting another error - "Warning: mysql_connect(): Access denied for user 'user'@'id22253' (using password: YES) in D:\inetpub\wwwroot\website\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1482"

Comment: Is the MySQL server on the same system as the WordPress installation? If so, set DB_HOST to **localhost** to see if it works. If it's on a separate system, you're likely running into MySQL permissions issues.

Comment: I have set DB_HOST to localhost as per your suggestion. Now encountering an internal server error but I think that's because of the web.config file. Thanks ever so much for your help. I'll let you know if it's worked when I get the internal server error resolved!

Answer (score 0):

May be it's because of htaccess issue, 
try this guide http://www.electronmedia.in/wp/wordpress-blog-migration-from-linux-to-iiswindows-server/

Comment: This one won't be related to htaccess. It's definitely an issue in the PHP code itself, probably a not-properly-definined constant of DB_HOST.

Comment: @eyalix I'm fairly new to this and had actually used that guide. I'm unsure as to whether the htaccess file needs deleting completely or whether I just need to add a web.config file?

Comment: I haven't tried either moving between Linux to Windows server. htaccess is enough in Linux, follow the tutorial, it says you should create a web.config file.